# How to set <div> s inline: text, img, text, text

Tags: html, css, image, inline

At first I have to  that I read a lot of tutorials and still I don't know what am I doing wrong...

I would like to use 4 divs inline. In those divs I would like to put: text, image, text, text. And I would like the middle text to set automatically to the maximum width.

I wrote a simple code, just to show my problem:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: right; width: 100px; background-color: red">right</div>
    <div style="margin-right: 100px; background-color: blue">
        <div style="width: 100px; background-color: green">left</div>
        <div style="width: 100px; margin-left: 100px; background-color: pink">
            <img src="../zdjecia_przedmiotow/1_small.jpg" />

        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 200px; background-color: green">center</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And it looks like this:
[image]

I would like to do it using divs!
what am I missing?

Comment: (OT.) Don't complicate your life! Use a stylesheet (don't use inline styles!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to float those divs inside so they align next to each other. Then you can use `calc()` to make the last container take the rest of the width;

[**FLOAT EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/43msutu0/4/)

**OR**

You can use `display: table` on the parent and set the children to `display: table-cell` like so:

[**TABLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/43msutu0/3/)

Also I restructured this a bit since there was some unnecessary elements/styles in there:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="box box1">left</div>
   <div class="box box2">
      <img src="../zdjecia_przedmiotow/1_small.jpg" />
   </div>
   <div class="box box3">center</div>
   <div class="box box4">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
}

.box{
    float: left;
} 

.box1{
  width: 100px; 
  background-color: green;
}

.box2{
    width: 100px; 
    background-color: pink;
}

.box3{
    background-color: green;
    width:calc(100% - 300px);
}

.box4{
    width:100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[**CLEANER FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/43msutu0/5/)

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the HTML structure a bit and used floats. With the CSS left inline:

```
<div style="background-color:blue;">
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color: green; float:left;">left</div>
    <img src="../zdjecia_przedmiotow/1_small.jpg" style="width: 100px; background-color: pink; float:left;" />
    <div style="background-color: green; width:calc(100% - 300px); float:left;">center</div>
    <div style="width: 100px; background-color: red; float:right;">right</div>
</div>
```

After CSS is out:

```
.box{background-color:blue}
.left{width: 100px; background-color: green; float:left;}
.fill{background-color: pink; width:calc(100% - 300px);}
.right{width: 100px; background-color: red; float:right;}

<div class="box">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <img class="left" src="../zdjecia_przedmiotow/1_small.jpg"/>
    <div class="left fill">center</div>
    <div style="right">right</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p4fqyr8e/2/)